# C# multidimensional array into array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have string array `["x3;s4;r4", "x2;s6;r7", ...]` that contains sort of 'multidimensional' data. I do following LINQ:

```
var fieldsArrays = data.Select(s => s.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

This query returns true multidimensional array `[["x3", "s4", "r4"], [...]]`
I need to select all values into a one dimensional array: `["x3", "s4", "r4", "x2", "s6"]`

What is the LINQ magic for this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) for this:

```
var fieldsArrays = data.SelectMany(s => s.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

You'll want to add a `.ToArray();` onto the end if you do actually want it back into an array (rather than acting as a view over `data`).

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/ZBUH48987)

Comment: So simple?! Works great. Give this man a beer! Thanks a lot (yeah and I feel like a 6 year old kid now...)